# How to send array of objects vith formData to woocommerc backend?

Tags: javascript, angular, wordpress, typescript, woocommerce

I am using angular for frontend and woocommerce for backend.
So i am trying to create Order with formData.
How to send array of objects to woocommerce ('line_items').

```
  createOrder(phone, address, metod, id, ukupno, orderArr: Array<Proizvod>) {
const formData = new FormData();
// append your data
formData.append('payment_method', metod);
formData.append('payment_method_title', metod);
formData.append('customer_id', id);
formData.append('billing[address_1]', address);
formData.append('billing[phone]', phone);
formData.append('shipping[address_1]', address);
formData.append('line_items', '') //ARRAY OF OBJECTS GO HERE
return new Promise(resolve => {

  this.http
    .post(
      `${this.wooc.url}/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/?consumer_key=${this.wooc.consumerKey
      }&consumer_secret=${this.wooc.consumerSecret}`,
      formData
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
      resolve(data);
    });
});
```

}

Comment: i am trying JSON.stringfy(array) but its not working. Getting 'line_items' is not object.

Comment: never used that API but maybe this is relevant? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/309504